# In Kentico, is there a way to convert an Email Feed (in email marketing) from Newsletter to Email Campaign?

Tags: email, kentico, newsletter

In Kentico, is there a way to convert an Email Feed (in email marketing) from Newsletter to Email Campaign? Even if it requires coding?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible!

Have you looked at the modules and the referenced database tables? I'd suggest starting there and working, in code, to get your email feed and create an email campaign.  It won't be a 1 to 1 match but you should be able to fill in the blanks with either real data or false.